# How do you get Finviz to show more news headlines for a particular stock?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, algorithmic-trading

At the moment, Finviz seems to only be showing a limited nuber of headlines per stock, creating huge discrepancies in data amongst multiple different stocks. Is there a way to get Finviz to, for example, show all the headlines within a given timeframe? I am trying to use this to create a sentiment analysis tool in Python, but I don't know if that's important.

Thank you!